# Is there a way for TypeScript to infer the type/this of an object?

Tags: typescript

The following block of code is legal in TypeScript but not in Flow:

```
var o = {
  x: 1,
  foo() { this.x = 'a'; }
};

o.foo();
```

I can make it fail if I create an interface for the object:

```
interface Obj {
    x: number;
    foo(this: Obj): void;
}

var o = {
  x: 1,
  foo(this: Obj) { this.x = 'a'; }
};

o.foo();
```

Is there a TypeScript compile option to make it work like Flow? (i.e. not need the interface)

Comment: How can you have a parameter named `this`?

Comment: It's the only way I know for TypeScript to check the type of 'this'. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html and search for "this parameters"

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to, the outer type hasn't been fully defined in the context of that function. But you don't necessarily need to define an interface for it, you could just use a regular object type literal adding properties as they are used.

Answer (score 0):

It infers the type for `o` eventually, it just can't do that until o is completely initialized. In this example, it gives the desired error only for the second assignment:

```
var o = {
    x: 1,
    foo() { this.x = 'a'; }
};


o.x = 'b';
```

> z.ts(7,1): error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type
>   'number'.

If you try to be explicit and use `typeof o` for `this` type the result is surprising:

```
var o = {
    x: 1,
    foo(this: typeof o) { this.x = 'a'; }
};


o.x = 'b';
```

No errors. But why? For explanation, try to compile the same code with --noImplicitAny:

> z.ts(1,5): error TS7022: 'o' implicitly has type 'any' because it does
>   not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in
>   its own initializer.

So I made it worse by "referencing it directly or indirectly in its own initializer".

The only way around it seems to define `foo` function outside `o` object. Fortunately, typescript is OK with referencing `typeof o` before `o` is defined:

```
function foo(this: typeof o) { this.x = 'a'; }

var o = {
    x: 1,
    foo: foo
};

o.foo();
```

> t.ts(1,32): error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type
>   'number'.